# How to bind value of a button in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I bind values of buttons in Vuejs ? actually i am looking for something like:

```
<b-button-group>
     <b-btn value="one" v-model="stateButtons">one</b-btn>
     <b-btn value="two" v-model="stateButtons">two</b-btn>
     <b-btn value="three" v-model="stateButtons">three</b-btn>
</b-button-group>

<p>Chossen: {{stateButtons}}</p>  // show the value of selected button
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
<b-button-group>
     <b-btn value="one"  @click="stateButtons = "one">one</b-btn>
     <b-btn value="two" @click="stateButtons = "two">two</b-btn>
     <b-btn value="three" @click="stateButtons = "three">three</b-btn>
</b-button-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap button group doesn't allow any `v-model` attribute so you can do it manually like

```
  <b-button-group >
      <b-btn @click="stateButtons = 'one'">one</b-btn>
      <b-btn  @click="stateButtons = 'two'">two</b-btn>
      <b-btn @click="stateButtons = 'three'">three</b-btn>
    </b-button-group>

    <p>Chossen: {{stateButtons}}</p>
```